# JBOSS IntellijIdea 14 Maven exploded war debug issue

Tags: maven, debugging, jboss, intellij-14, exploded

I am trying to run my maven web app exploded war in debug mode, I put a breakpoint in java class and started the jboss server using intellijidea debug button.

It looks like this: I am using default port set by intellijidea which is 57240. Server is starting fine, I can run my application. But somehow application is not stopping at any debug point.

I am following these instructions:
http://wiki.jetbrains.net/intellij/Debugging_applications_for_JBoss_AS#Debugging_the_sample_application

Any idea what could I be missing?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I figured out configuration after some trial and error.
Here is my configuration looking like.

[image]

[image]

After all this setup just hit debug button and set the breakpoints.